# Is there a simple Rich Text Editor with content update ability?

Tags: jquery, rich-text-editor

I need to replace the textarea with html content. So basically I need a very simple RTE. I tested few but none of them is good.

Very important: I need a RTE where I can update the contents of the RTE by code. for example

```
$("#editor").rteplugin("content", "<b>Hello</b>");
```

Can you recommend something simple?

Comment: CKeditor is very easy to use - http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at TinyMCE, used it multiple times with great success. It has a lot of functionality but you can use it in a cut-down form.

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent)

Check the above link. The below is a simple implementation of it

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "tinymce",
        theme: "simple"
    });
```

Comment: Exactly. TinyMCE is an established tool and comes with a vast, but scalable set of functions. Unless you're trying to avoid TinyMCE for some reason, I would also call this the way to go.